# Fatal error: Class 'Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data' not found in /home/ashoocom/public_html/Magento/ashoo/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

Today i uploaded my `Magento Project` to my Domain everything works fine but when i try to open configration from `admin` its show this error

> Fatal error: Class 'Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data' not found
>   in /home/ashoocom/public_html/Magento/ashoo/app/Mage.php on line 547

after editing `Magestore_Magenotification.xml` in `/app/etc/modules` i.e changed from *true* to *false*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magestore_Magenotification>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magestore_Magenotification>
    </modules>
</config>
```

then i am able to open `configration` from `admin` panel

now first off all i don't know that why its being used is it fine to leave it false??
if not then what should i do?
in addition i don't have `config.xml` file in my theme as i searched this problem on google and many people suggested to make changes in `config.xml` and `local.xml`

please help
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error code posted above does the following file exist on your server `app/code/community/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/Data.php` or `app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/Data.php`? If it doesn't it means your missing the helper file that came with the extension.

If you leave the module turned off it means the module will not work.

Comment: I checked yess you are right i don,t have Magenotification Folder in app/code/community/Magestore/  ..What should i do now from where can i get it?

But i have this app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/Data.php file .

Comment: Does the rest of the module reside in the community folder? So do all the files live in local or community?

Comment: Yes all modules are there but Magenotification folder is missing in app/code/community/Magestore

Comment: sorry i don't think you understood, where does all the Magenotification folder's live is it all under community or local. If all the module is under community but the helper file is in local do you know why it was added to local? if not then you would need to move the helper back to community or move all the Magenotification folders to local.

Comment: Sorry for mis-understanding ..yess all the module (Magenotification folder's) lives in Local .i Copied (Magenotification to app/code/community/Magestore and then changed Magestore_Magenotification.xml again from false to true and then flushed cache but still no success and recieving same error

Comment: Did you update `<codePool>community</codePool>`  in `/app/etc/modules`  `Magestore_Magenotification.xm`l

Comment: yes i have tried it but no still same error

Comment: Are you able to upload screen shots to your answer of where the files are located and the `Magestore_Magenotification.xml`

Comment: i have uploaded images of folder structure please check.

Comment: @YousafAli just checked this images, It looks like you are still missing the `Data.php` That lives in `app/code/community/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/` Download the module again from here http://www.magestore.com/magento-new-order-admin-email-notification-extension.html and that should have the helper file

Answer (score 1):

1.Check your module config file of Magestore under app/etc/modules and make sure all of these module should be enable.
eg:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Magestore_Magenotification>
                <active>active</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Magestore_Magenotification>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

2. Check your Module under app/code/local/Magestore.
 for notificatio module and second in app/code/community/Magestore.
3.All these module should be enable.